# Why leave King's Landing now?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, game-of-thrones

**SPOILERS for those yet to see [Game of Thrones](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0944947/) Season 4 Episode 10 [The Children](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3060860/?ref_=ttep_ep10)**

> As soon as the bells start to toll for *Tywin's* death, *Varys* turns and takes a seat in the ship about to sail with *Tyrion*. I understand that he might do this because he fears people in King's Landing will suspect his hand in this deed. But it seemed like an impromptu decision on his part.

**Why leave King's Landing now, all of a sudden?** If he had anticipated this danger while freeing *Tyrion*, why not pack his belongings and be gone for good?

**EDIT:** In light of the recent comments, it seems I need to clarify my and the question's stand at the moment. The question is not about *Varys's* motive to help *Tyrion* or the reasons for his departure. Rather **his decision to leave seemed rather abrupt**, something he had not anticipated. *What made him change his plans?* *Why does he think he can't be in King's Landing anymore?*

Comment: +1 - Ah, wanted to ask the exact same question, too. Especially since I always felt *Varys* to be a permanent feature of this city, if he leaves then times are definitely changing.

Comment: To be honest, this question is very premature and impossible to answer without a fair few spoilers...

Comment: @AndrewMartin - very premature?  If it were not for the books it would still be a perfectly good analysis question - of course with the books (as you point out), its hard to answer without reference to them and therefore making spoilers inevitable.

Comment: I do suggest (as people have already done) - spoilers from the books should be in spoiler markup here.

Comment: @iandotkelly Which seems also to be the (admittedly hard to filter and decypher) consensus of [the related meta discussion](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1241/49).

Comment: @iandotkelly: I always think any question about an episode that has just aired with an obvious cliffhanger when we KNOW there are external sources is premature. Why ask the question when you can just google the books and find out. If you want to know based SOLELY on what we've seen on the tv series thus far, then the question will be obviously incomplete and opinionated.

Comment: @iandotkelly: It's just my opinion. If this was the last episode of Breaking Bad Season 4, I'd get it. Discuss away. But when a whole series of books exists, it's easy to find the answer. How is this difference to a simple IMDB trivia question that we don't allow as it can be googled easily?

Comment: @iandotkelly: I might sound like I'm having a rant. I'm really not! I did enjoy answering it, but I just always feel questions like this are very premature, as almost any tv show will end an episode or a series on a cliffhanger these days.

Comment: @AndrewMartin That is something I would definitely not sign. There might very well be a perfectly good and valid explanation in the *existing* TV material that the asker just didn't get. Of course one could (easily?) read the books or look at a complete summary including future stuff to get the answers, but not always is this necessary nor desirable. *You* certainly know that there isn't a better answer outside of the books yet, but *the OP* (as well as I for that matter) apparently doesn't.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: That's why I think it's premature. The OP doesn't know - why not wait at least a few episodes into the next season to find out, rather than asking for an explanation of the final scene of the series! Still, there's no real discussion here. The question is just fine, I was airing my views. I think there was a similar GoT question a while back that I felt the same way about and we discussed it there too. I know I'm in the minority though, so I'll shut up... for now ;)

Comment: @AndrewMartin Apart from that I for myself don't want to do much elaborate research at all, otherwise I wouldn't ask a single question here. ;-)

Comment: @AndrewMartin - don't worry - I'm not taking it as a rant, just enjoying the cut and thrust of discussion here :)  For the record, I do think that its possible to attempt to answer this from the existing TV material, even if there might be more accurate answers that include source material.  For what it is worth, I think Varys probably decided that with Tommen (and therefore Cersei) now essentially in charge of the throne, with (relatively) moderating characters such as Tywin now out of the picture - he wouldn't want to be around when it is suspected he helped Tyrion escape justice.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are a lot of answers that draw knowledge from the Books, but from what I can gather the TV series is carving its own narrative.

As an answer from the TV series *only*;

Varys agrees to help Tyrion escape, and expects this to happen *to schedule*.

When Tyrion delays this, by paying his father a visit, he changes the circumstances of the plan, including its timing. Under the original plan Varys had prepared, there would have been plenty of time for Tyrion to have been escorted to the docks and for Varys to get back, removing a calculated amount of suspicion. When the alarm sounds, Varys would have had to sneak back in to the Red Keep and create a last minute Alibi. He may or may not know what Tyrion has done; but he knows *something*... I think Tyrions actions have forced his hand. Varys didn't intend on leaving Kings Landing at that point in time, but circumstances left him no choice. His mind was made up on the jetty, and not a moment before...

Comment: I've edited it as spoiler boxes need some separating text otherwise they don't work (which sucks!)

Comment: +1 - Very good answer. But seeing that the question is about exactly the same episode that the answer uses as it's sole source of information, the actual benefit of spoiler boxes eludes me here (especially since the answer doesn't make the slightest sense without the hidden text).

Comment: @napoleon, sure, was just temporary for courtesy  really!  It only aired in the UK last night, I don't want people making the same mistakes I have done..

Comment: I think your last section is spot on - it's pretty clear with with the line "What have you done?" that things did not go as planned. Also, it appears he was heading back to the city when the bells starting ringing, and then he turns around.

Comment: @corsiKa, that was exactly my interpretation of it. He seems to pause and think "I'm not sure even I could talk my way out of this", then kinda sits down in resignation.

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional: Your answer is exactly in line with my question. Maybe I'll edit my question and clarify my point a bit for future answers.

Answer (score 5):

I'll try to answer this question, although spoilers will be rife.

Who does Varys serve? Remember back to his conversation with Ned Stark in Season 1:

> Eddard Stark: "Tell me something, Varys. Who do you truly serve?"
>   Varys: "The realm, my lord. Someone must."

Varys may or may not be lying. We don't know. Up until now though, we know that he is playing a game, like Littlefinger and all the others. We also know that he knows much more about Daenerys than he lets on.

Arya Stark, again in Season 1, overheard him talking underneath the Red Keep to Illyrio Mopatis, the man who was looking after Dany and Viserys. At the time, their conversation is confusing, but as the series' continues it becomes more and more obvious what they were discussing. From the [wiki](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Illyrio_Mopatis):

> ...Illyrio pays a secret visit to King's Landing where
>   he discusses their mutual plans with his ally, Varys, in the secret
>   passages under the Red Keep. Once Khal Drogo's son is born, the
>   Dothraki can move to invade Westeros and Viserys can retake the Iron
>   Throne. However, Westeros must be in chaos and civil war before this
>   happens. When Varys warns that a civil war, launched by a conflict
>   between House Stark and House Lannister, is imminent, Illyrio becomes
>   concerned that things are moving too fast, but Varys suggests
>   motivating the Dothraki to move faster might be a viable strategy.
>   They talk about how new Hand of the King, Eddard Stark, now has the
>   same genealogy book that his predecessor read, and has met Robert's
>   bastard son Gendry: the same evidence which led Jon Arryn to discover
>   the truth about Queen Cersei's children. They discuss the possibility
>   that the same fate may befall Lord Stark as did his predecessor.

This is incredibly important and was revealed very early on in the series. Whilst Robert wants Dany killed and Varys agrees quietly, he has no intention of doing this. Spoilers:

> He is revealed in the books to actually *warn* Jorah Mormont that this is the King's intention and to be careful. The poisoner in Season 1 acted on his own accord, *not* on Varys'. See [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37908/how-is-the-murder-attempt-consistent-with-varys-plan) for more information.

Now, in the books all of this isn't revealed until Book 5 - the series is *very* premature in showing us all of this, revealing it all by midway through Season 1.

However, since it does reveal it all, we *know* that Varys' has plans for Daenerys and is in league with Ilyrio to protect her (for what end and reason, we don't know beyond his supposed desire to serve the realm).

Now, all of this is spoilerific and describes books 4 and 5 (and thus likely Season 5):

> In the books, Cersei effectively rules as Tommen is too young. She is paranoid, incompetent and surrounds herself with allies who give her poor advice. Jaime grows distant from her. In the books, there is a Lannister, Tyrek, who disappears during the riot of King's Landing shown in Season 2. Jaime begins to suspect Varys had a part in this. There is also some speculation that Varys had some part in a puppet show that begins to be shown in the capital, discussing how a kingdom is ruled by arrogant, greedy lions. A stag stands up to them, but he is eaten. Finally, a dragon hatches and burns all the lions. Cersei is outraged. She puts to death the creators of the show, takes half the wealth from anyone wealthy who watched it and takes an eye from those who don't have wealth.

Following these minor mentions of Varys, in Book 5:

> Kevan Lannister effectively takes control of the kingdom after Cersei is ruined. However, Varys enters Pycelle's chambers and kills him, before finally using his little birds to have Kevan Lannister summoned and killing him. He basically tells him this is because he is doing too good a job reversing all of Cersei's incompetent and moronic actions. Her actions are sowing rife and discontent between the Lannister, the Tyrells and leaving the realm open for the taking. There is another heir to the throne (besides Dany - more spoilers!) and he intends to make the realm ripe for the taking.

So after ALL THAT, including many spoilers:

> His leaving the realm is consistent with his overall plan. When he sees Tyrion leaving, he *knows* it is a good time to leave to. His overall plan is truly underway and he knows Cersei, now mad with power and rage, will continue to ruin the realm. With Stannis far away, Renly gone, the Starks gone and the Tyrells and Lannisters fighting, it's the perfect time for his long-in-waiting plan to finally be put into full swing.

Comment: *"the series is very premature in showing us all of this, revealing it all by midway through Season 1."* - Yet I'm not sure that the TV show makes it as clear that *Varys* sides with *Daenerys* as you make it sound. His conversation with *Illyrio* in the basement was rather cryptic and to me seemed as if he just collected information about her in order to prevent her advancement (or at least keep a suspicious eye on it). Your answer was the first time I even thought about considering him to be in favor of her...

Comment: ...Maybe your existing book-knowledge about the actual truth helped you to interpret the event in the TV-show this way, or I just wasn't smart/attentive enough to understand that part in its intended way.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: Perhaps. I could go back and spoiler it if you think so, but another way of looking at it is this. If you watch Series 1, it's fairly meaningless. Watch Series 1, 2, 3, 4, then go back and watch Series 1 and you'll suddenly understand *a lot* more about what they're talking about.

Comment: That aside, I didn't want to imply that it should be spoilered, anyway. I guess I'll look that scene up again.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: It's an interesting point you raise. I saw the first two series (a few times) before I read the books, and I'd definitely twigged *something* about that scene. But it's certainly possible the books fleshed it out even more for me. Bloody hard to tell with GoT sometimes!!

Comment: *"Bloody hard to tell with GoT sometimes!"* - Well, this whole problem of a parallely developed book and TV continuity is an interesting (and IMHO unique) thing anyway, especially from a writing standpoint (and I feel a question about that coming up).

Comment: @NapoleonWilson, we definitely have some pretty unique problems on M&TV due to the medium we operate in: we've *a lot* of policy to firm up before we get to that graduation date...

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional Well, I wouldn't really see it that seriously, though, whatever it is in particular that you're after. But I agree that *Game of Thrones* in particular seems to have potential for repeatedly causing trouble with regard to spoilers and book-TV conflicts in general.

Comment: @AndrewMartin: No offense, but I feel you might have jumped the gun and a little off-track with your answer in respect to the question. You have very ably (_and at length_), explained the reasons for Varys to leave the city and his actual purpose. However, I was seeking an answer to his abrupt change in plans. Will be making an edit to the question in line with this shortly.

Answer (score 4):

So in a show sense, there isn't much to go on until Season 5 airs in 2015 (and if I can help it, when I will revisit this question).

There can be some speculation as you said that he might be implicated in releasing Tyrion, being a past friend of him and Jaime is essentially immune (in a sense) to Cersei's madness.

However in the books:

> [*He vanishes without a trace.*](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Varys#A_Feast_for_Crows)  And later does not return in the books until near the end of [*A Dance With Dragons*](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/A_Dance_with_Dragons)  So Varys going on the ship with Tyrion actually fits the story well and gives context to where he might have been.